# (C) Display a Calender using days in the month and the day the month starts ( using 1 for Monday , 2 for Tuesday etc.)

Tags: c, calendar, formatting

This is what it should look like when the data is entered

[image: calendar]

I have done the first part in order to input the data

```
  #include <stdio.h>
int a, b, c, weekday, i, day, month;
int main() {
printf("Number of days in the month: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
while(true){

if((a <= 31) && (a >= 28)){
    break;
} else { 
    printf("invalid data try again :");
    scanf("%d", &a);

}
}
 printf("Code for the starting day:");
scanf("%d", &b);
 printf("\nMo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa  So\n");
}
```

I have updated with a redone first part , to make sure the data is valid and the printf to do the heading

Comment: Is this a home work? Yesterday same question was asked here.

Comment: @haccks They don't collaborate well, it seems.

Comment: hmmn i searched but couldn't see any similar questions. where about can i find that question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
printf("\nMo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa Su\n" );

if(weekday < 7)
for(i=0; i<weekday; i++)
        printf("    " );

for ( day = 1; day <= days_in_month[month]; day++ )
{
    printf("%02d", day );


    if ( ( day + weekday) % 7 > 0 ){
        printf("   " );
    }
    else{
        printf("\n " );
    }
}
```

Comment: We are covering 'for' next week so i don't really follow this, i Believe we are meant to use a while loop and print the right number of spaces using a counter. then another loop to continue writing numbers until the  days in a month is reached